# association from term document matrix

Tags: r, text, machine-learning, text-mining

Is there a way to find associated words from a term document matrix , other than using findAssoc() in r. My objective is to find all words with decided frequency (lets say if i want to find all wrods with freq more than 200)and then find words which were appearing with these words.

Answer (score 0):

`findAssoc()` has a `terms` argument. E.g. feed it with the words, which have a frequency greater than 200. You can find those words by using `findFreqTerms()`.

Comment: Hi Luke , Thank you for your help. My aim is to find words that appear with a particular word. e.g if issue is a term with frequency 200 in my tdm, and i am looking to find all words that has appeared with "issue". Can this be done ?